# create a new column with a value from rows

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, analysis

I have a data table as below
[image]

I want to put "a" to a column like below:
[image]

Comment: Can you upload your code?

Answer (score 0):

Delete row:

```
df = df.drop(0, axis=0)
```

Add column :

```
df.insert(0,"",["a","","",""])
```

First, you need to learn how to use pandas.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,2,3,4],'c':[1,2,3,4]})
print(df1)
df2 = df1.drop([0])
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'': [1,' ', ' ']})
df4 = pd.concat([df3,df2],axis = 1)
print(df4)

  a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
   a  b  c
0  2  2  2
1  3  3  3
2  4  4  4
      a  b  c
0  1  2  2  2
1     3  3  3
2     4  4  4
```